# Maven artifact for Java EE and hibernate

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven

I'm looking for a Maven artifact which can generate code for a Java EE web application + Hibernate + Spring. It should use JDK 1.6.

Where can I find a stable maven repository?

Comment: Are you talking about an "archetype" instead of an "artifact" ?

Comment: How about a google search before asking or is your time more precious than everyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The Maven Repo for [Hibernate](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate).
- The list of Maven Repo for [Spring](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/).

Here is the `dependency` for Java EE 6.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Codehaus has an overview of archetypes, many with spring and hibernate:

[Archetypes List](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List)